# File format of substitution matrix in clustalw

Tags: sequence-alignment, multiple-sequence-alignment, substitution-model

I need to set the substitution matrix used by command line CLUSTALW when comparing DNA sequences to:

```
 0 -1 -1 -1
-1  0 -1 -1 
-1 -1  0 -1
-1 -1 -1  0
```

from my understanding I need to pass the location of a file with the matrix to the `-dnamatrix` parameter, however, I cannot find out what format the file is supposed to be in. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [example](https://www.biostars.org/p/133912/) seems to have information on this, looks like it should have this format:

```
   A   G   C   T   U   *
A  1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
G  -1  1   -1  -1  -1  -1
C  -1  -1  1   -1  -1  -1
T  -1  -1  -1  1   -1  -1
U  -1  -1  -1  -1  1   -1
*  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
```

However, the page I linked is specifically about a bug regarding ClustalW **ignoring** custom made matrices. It's a pretty old post so it might have been fixed since. However, if you encounter that bug, that same page thankfully does contain a workaround!